# Why? The best way to code with interface in java?

Tags: java

What is main reason of coding with interfaces not with the implemented classes in java. i don't What is strong reason behind it.. can anyone guide me

Comment: Explain your question more.

Comment: Come up with your code & problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the [*Dependency Inversion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) principle.

In a nutshell:

1. High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.
2. Abstractions should not depend on details. Details should depend on abstractions.

An interface is an abstraction, an implementation is a detail. By making your program elements depend on interfaces, you free yourself from depending on details. When you don't depend on details, then if the details change, the rest of the program doesn't need to be recompiled.

See the linked wiki page for a more detailed explanation.